# Using async/await pattern to download multiple documents

Tags: c#, concurrency, async-await

I would like to experiement a little bit with these new keywords introduced in C# 5. I am interested in looking at how to distribute work in a concurrent manner. I would more naturraly do it with a thread pool but was interested on doing the same with this new asynchronous pattern.

So here is my toy example , I am writing a crawler that will crawl from n root sites and follow link down further. Is there any good concurrency pattern to write this app.

Comment: There are many articles on the Internet about exactly this example, have you tried looking at them?

Comment: Would you ming spotting one. I have not really found one on this. One thing to notice it is not about a thread pool or async/await it is about using both at the same time

Comment: @Dave: What benefit does the thread pool have here? How did you want to use it?

Comment: [One such article by Bill Wagner.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/jj573641.aspx) And when you're using `async` to download files, you don't need ThreadPool.

Comment: @svick: Sound interesting will read it now as Stephen Taub one (see below). I agree with the fact that you don't need a thread pool to start an async method. What I really don't get is how you schedule you downloads ( no more that 2 active downloads on the same domain , a total of 10 concurrent downloads for instance).

Comment: @Dave Yeah, doing that is not that simple. A good way is to use `ActionBlock` from TPL Dataflow.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the threading technology used, you need a manager to hand out the work load to the individual workers. The manager will create 1-N number of the worker processes. Within the worker processes they will do the target threadining methodology you choose.

I recommend that you create an interface which each of these workers will need to adhere to and within the interface it specifies a start method which takes the url, an possible error conditions which are public and can be checked, the ability to stop the process and a way to hand off data when the work is finished assuming no errors. Finally a status such as an enum, as to whether it is currently working or stopped or stopped with errors.

Then the manager can simply create each process by handing off the target URL and putting the working unit into its own internal queue. The manager then goes through the queue looking for items which mark themselves as finished and then hands off the data to a GUI(?) to show to the end user.

So how will this new async await pattern fit it? You simply make the call using async await within your worker class and process the data as needed. The manager does not need to know because the class communicates with the manager via the interface methods.

Here are some documents to get you started on the async await pattern:

[The Task-Based Async Await Pattern](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957) (download word) by Stephen Toub

[Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)